# How to make ViewModel aware of conversion error

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am designing a WPF application following MVVM. My `ViewModel` is exposing one `Double` property called DoubleValue, which is binding to a `TextBox` in the `View`. I have set "ValidatesOnDataErrors=True" for the binding. So if the user types a string which can't be converted to a `Double`, it display the red background.

In my `ViewModel` I also have a `Command` object, let's call SaveCommand, whose CanExecute delegate is depending on whether there is any error in the VM (my ViewModelBase class implements `IDataErrorInfo`, I have an overridable ValidatePropertyByName function and the validation errors are stored in a dictionary.) But now my problem is, if I give an invalid string in the `TextBox`, since the conversion fails, it never calls the setter of the binding property value. In another word, the ValidatePropertyByName is not called and the error dictionary remains the previous state, which normally is clean. So if now the user click the Save button (which is enabled since the error dictionary is clean), the SaveCommand executes with the previous valid double value to save. This is obviously not good.

So how can I make my `ViewModel` aware of such conversion errors?

UPDATE:

Some code example:

The binding property is like this:

```
Public Property DoubleValue As Double
        Get
            Return _doubleValue
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            If value <> _doubleValue Then
                _doubleValue = value
                RaisePropertyChanged("DoubleValue")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _doubleValue As Double
```

My binding is like this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding DoubleValue, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

And now my problem is: if I give a string "XXX" in the text box, since it can't be converted to a double value, the setter of DoubleValue is never get called. And so the property value remains the previous(valid) value. Now if my SaveCommand gets executed, it will do the save operation with this previous valid value, which will make the user confused.

Comment: Can you please add some example code to your question, that describe your MVVM setup and problem

Comment: @Jehof I updated with some code example. Thanks!

Comment: Besides my longer answers below, if it is enough for you, you can simply use a Fallbackvalue like: 
 <TextBox Text="{Binding ..., Converter={...}, FallbackValue='Invalid input', TargetNullValue='Please enter a value'}"  />

Comment: I don't see the problem... if a user is so stupid that they enter `XXX` into a numerical field and then they press `Save` despite a red warning border on the `TextBox`, then that is their problem and not yours... if you really want to stop idiots from doing that, then just add a handler to the `Textbox` to not allow them to enter non numerical values. Simple.

Comment: @Sheridan , at least one problem is, the `Save` command is generally only enabled when `ViewModel` passes the Validation. But since the the conversion is not part of the VM validation, it provides really bad UX: the user inputs an out of range value, e.g., -1 for a period duration, the Save is disabled. But if the user provide "XXX", the Save is enabled.

Comment: I totally understand the situation... I just don't see it as a problem. Your `Save` command is still only enabled when your `ViewModel` passes the Validation. If a user enters `XXX` into a numerical field, it will rightly be ignored (in terms of the valid data in the view model). That is a UI error, not a data error, so handle it in the UI... like the red warning border, or just filter out non numeric key presses. In WPF, total validation is achieved in two parts; data validation in the model or view model and UI control input validation in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply put these two things together. One is the regular validation inside the ViewModel. The other are control-specific problems, like unconvertible values.

So there are two possible ways to solve this:

1) Don't use a converter. Just bind the string. Inside the ViewModel you can then use the validation to check for a valid value. (More MVVM)

2) Store your ValidationErrors on the controlside and merge them with the viewmodel errors. This is not easy but a good way to create one source for binding against ALL problems within your UI. We are doing this for complex textboxes at work. This means manual code in the controls but for complex customcontrols this is OK, I believe.

edit: just to elaborate a little on the 2nd point. We are having a DependencyProperty of Type ObservableCollection inside the Control. Then you can bind this Collection to a ViewModel Property and as soon as your control moves an Error inside the collection it is available inside the viewModel. You can then use this collection inside your validation implementation. This works pretty well for larger controls.

Edit2: For the MarkInvalid Stuff I mentioned in the comment. It would look like this:

```
DataErrorValidationRule validationRule = new DataErrorValidationRule();
ValidationError validationError = new ValidationError(validationRule, myTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)) { ErrorContent = "My custom message" };
Validation.MarkInvalid(myTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty), validationError);
```

You would call in from inside a TextChanged when you can't convert the new given value or

```
Validation.ClearInvalid(myTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty))
```

Maybe that will help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1) seems really counter-intuitive and the properties kind of lose their meanings. I see what you mean by 2), but is there a simpler way? I mean when we perform the VM validation, we practically bind the error message to Validation class object. Can't we somehow specify this binding as two way?

Comment: Well the point is IDataErrorInfo is nothing more than saying is my ViewModel valid. It does say nothing about values from user input that never reach your VM.
I can only think of the 2 possibilities I proposed. Option 1 is the far simpler and I believe it is not counterintuitive. All you do is move the conversion from the binding to the viewmodel which is absolutely fine. You will have one string and one double property meaning inside your vm you can work with the real value but the textual representation is a string you're binding against.
Besides that option 2 works good for us (huge app)

Comment: Maybe in Addition: if you only want to show errors directly on the control you should look into: Validation.MarkInvalid and ClearInvalid. This calls will mark the binding as having an error forcing the error provider to show up with a custom message fe. "Conversion error". BUT... again this can only be done from inside the control. So you'd need an User/CustomControl with a textbox, parse input, try to convert, then call markinvalid or clearinvalid.

Comment: But it still doesn't change IDataErrorInfo Item (I admit that maybe it shouldn't change) and hence can't change CanExecute status of Command object. Well, I said the 1) is counter-intuitive because this string conversion is more like specific to TextBox, but what if we want to bind the same property to a different control type (the all string properties still work but become unnecessary)? The VM is of course view-specific but it should somehow allow some flexibility.

Comment: I guess we can draw the conclusion that there is no simpler way, which does not require some effect. In my opinion this conversion error should be reflected in IDataErrorInfo item.

Comment: No it doesn't change the VM. Option 2 does though. :)
For the string properties: I think you take that too strict. String are the only way for loose user input. If you switch to another control with loose input you still need strings. Else, your concept changed -> you need to rewrite anyways. That's the price you pay for moving UI logic to a viewModel BUT-> what's when you start using UnitTest f.e. You can simply test all your conversion logic automated :D

Answer (score 2):

the most easy way is to just use string properties in your viewmodel. then you get all input from the user and can validate it in your viewmodel. the drawback is that you have to convert the values to the right type when you go to the model.

if you dont want this you have to create your own controls or better behaviors so that the use can just input values that your viewmodel expect. eg. NumericInputBehavior.

Comment: Regarding all string properties, my feeling is it makes the ViewModel less generic (aside from making it hard to understand). What if we want to bind the property to a different Control type? Then the all-string feature becomes somehow unnecessary. Even though ViewModel is View-specific, but I still think it should allow some flexibility. About the Control behavior, can it incorporate with `Command` in ViewModel? I mean can we pass this "wrong text format" error to ViewModel, which will check CanExecute then (my feeling is it still needs some additional efforts)?